# How to generate double numbers in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, numbers, double

Thanks everyone i got the library of numbers, but i still have a problem.
This code bellow is only able to generate all numbers from 0.000000000000000000000000000001 to 0.999999999999999999999999999999
,but i need ALL NUMBERS from 0.009999999999999999999999999999 to 0.099999999999999999999999999999.
So i modified it and know its stuck on 0.01, so its printing in a file only 0.01 every time its in a loop, and it's not getting bigger!
BENDER BENDING please help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace double_generator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xexex\Desktop\green.txt"))
            {
                double number = 0.009999999999999999999999999999;

                do
                {
                    number += 0.000000000000000000000000000001;
                    file.WriteLine(number.ToString("N30"));
                } while (number <= 0.099999999999999999999999999999);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I need to have them all in txt file or cmd. All numbers from 0.000000000000000000000000000001 to 0.999999999999999999999999999999.

Comment: So, `javascript` or `c#`? Please don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: Such a huge file cannot exist! There are about `10**30` numbers there. If each single number takes up 30 bytes, say, that would be `3 * 10**31`  (a.k.a. `3e31`) bytes. No system can hold such a huge file.

Comment: Darn it @JeppeStigNielsen. You beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: The double precision is limited, so the representable amount of numbers in the range is about 1E18, if I calculated it right. But it is still too much to store.

Comment: Please read this article before asking another question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Warning: the file produced is 33 gigabytes! The file is so large it is actually impossible to open.

```
try
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user_pc\Desktop\test.txt"))
    {
        double number = 0;
        do
        {
            number += 0.000000000000000000000000000001;
            file.WriteLine(number.ToString("N30"));
        } while (number <= 0.999999999999999999999999999999);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `double` does not have enough precision. You will reach some point where `number += 0.000000000000000000000000000001` no longer changes the `number` before you get close to the end target. But of course, the file system will give up before that.

Comment: Should it be a float then? @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: Actually I cant even get 15 decimal points to work.

Comment: No, a `float` would be even worse.

Comment: BTW: It would need many centuries to write that file.

Comment: You could use a `BigInteger` if you included the `System.Numerics.dll` in your references. Then something like `using (var writer = File.CreateText(@"C:\TooLong.txt")) { var end = BigInteger.Pow(10, 30); for (BigInteger bi = 1; bi < end; bi++) { writer.WriteLine("0." + bi.ToString("D30")); } }` would work in principle. However it must fail because the file system cannot give you such a huge file (see my comment elsewhere).

Comment: Bender Bending You are a genus.

Answer (score 1):

What about generating every number by adding 0.000000000000000000000000000001 at a time in a for loop, that ends when the number equals 0.999999999999999999999999999999.

In each iteration convert it to string and write it to the file

Comment: I might have misunderstood your request, do you want to generate every single double number or just generate a random double between 0 and 1?

Comment: I deleted mine, I'm pretty sure he meant every one. Which means your approach should work just fine

Comment: I think he wants a random number generator. Edit: Just read his comment, nvm.

Comment: I need to generate every double number.

Comment: its going to take really really long about some million years!